# Is it possible to use a Xeon Phi in a Mac running OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, hpc

A colleague of ours is willing to lend our lab a Xeon Phi (2012 model, the one with passive cooling) that he has no use for. The only machine we could physically put this beast into is a Mac Pro (2011 model, the good old "cheese grater"). Before we install the Xeon Phi I would like to make sure that i) doing so won't ruin either the Phi or the Mac, and ii) it is possible to use the card when running OS X. The Internet (as seen through a Google bubble) did not deliver any definite answers on the subject.

If the Mac/Phi combination is a definite "no-no", then we'll have to buy a machine to host the Phi. In this case I would appreciate suggestions / experience reports. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Intel product support web-site, drivers for this beast only exist for Windows and various flavors of Linux.

You won't damage the hardware (it's a regular PCIe card as far as the hardware is concerned). Obviously the power-supply must be able to deliver the extra juice.
But you are going to need to run Windows or a Linux flavor on the Mac to make it work.